# Dendropy interop and numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm currently trying to work with the python Dendropy library and include some PAUP commands inside my code.

I'm having the matrix as a numpy array, but it looks like that there is a problem with numpy array and this module.

```
***Distance matrix A (Numpy array)***

[[ 0  2  7  8 16 17]
 [ 2  0  5  6 17 16]
 [ 7  5  0  9 15 13]
 [ 8  6  9  0 18 16]
 [16 17 15 18  0  5]
 [17 16 13 16  5  0]]
```

i've tried to transfrom the numpy array to numpy matrix using : `A=numpy.matrix(A)`

```
import dendropy
from dendropy.interop import paup     

#A is a distance matrix like this    

tree = paup.estimate_tree(A, 'nj')
```

The error I'm getting is: `AttributeError: 'matrix' object has no attribute 'write_to_stream'`

or :

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'write_to_stream'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used [DendroPy](http://packages.python.org/DendroPy/), but it is pretty clear from the error you reported and from a quick look at the DendroPy docs (e.g. http://packages.python.org/DendroPy/tutorial/chars.html and http://packages.python.org/DendroPy/tutorial/paup.html) that `estimate_tree` expects some sort of `CharacterMatrix` object (a class defined in DendroPy), *not* a NumPy array or matrix.

Comment: do you have any idea how would be the shape of this characterMatrix?? the tutorial does not mention anything about it

Comment: Sorry, no.  I was about suggest that you ask your question on the dendropy-users mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/dendropy-users), but it looks like you already have!  Or someone has else has asked almost the exact same question :)  (https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/dendropy-users/I1dz2wVDoF0)